# How to make SwiftUI responsive to different devices? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm doing this tutorial and it requires me to place numbers(`CGFloat`s) in for offset and padding, the problem is, this looks different on different devices. For example, on iPod touch, it goes off the screen.

My question is, how do I make these values change with the size of the screen? I know how to write a function to do this, so I guess I'm really asking: How do I retrieve the screen size data in order to use it?

```
CircleImage()
  .offset(y: -130)
  .padding(.bottom, -100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GeometryReader` to get the size of the view that the item is in and then make calculations based on the size.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Circle().offset(y: geometry.size.height / 4)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this just retrieves the size of the current `View` and by default expands to fill available space.

Additional reading on `GeometryReader`: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-provide-relative-sizes-using-geometryreader